# Open URL in new window/tab Javascript

Tags: tabs

I have searched through SO to see if I could find the answer and I sort of have, but cannot get it to work so I assume I am missing something.

I have a link that gets setup by options that are filled in to a form; I have had a go with window.open but am having no luck.  Apologies for my sheer idiocy on the subject.

```js
<script>
 function process()
 {
 var url="http://postorder.ebay.co.uk/Cancel/Start?transId=" + document.getElementById("order_id").value + "&itemId=" + document.getElementById("item_id").value;location.href=url;return false;
 }
</script>
```

```html
  <form id="ff" onSubmit="return process();">

         <label>
   <span>eBay Order ID*</span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter the Order ID" name="order_id" id="order_id" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You know how to find the Order ID right?')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required autofocus>
   </label>

   <label>
   <span>eBay Item ID*</span>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter the Item Number" name="item_id" id="item_id" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('You have the Order ID but this will not work without the Item Number')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required>
   </label>

   <input class="sendButton transition" type="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}`

Comment: Just tried and does not seem to work, I had seen something like that before which also seemed to be fruitless.  It does not seem to want to open up a new window/tab.  It just carries on in the same window without much thought.